# Android x86 bluetooth in Virtualbox

Tags: android, bluetooth, virtualbox

I am working on developing an app for Android that requires a bluetooth connection. I currently have the most recent version of android x86 installed using virtualbox on my linux mint 18.3 OS. Everything is working fine except one thing, bluetooth.

When I go to turn the bluetooth on, it says it is on temporarily, but then shuts off when I go back to the bluetooth settings.

[Image of bluetooth settings turned on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S96l8.png)

[Bluetooth settings after returning to general settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyIAV.png)

As you can see, the bluetooth doesn't actually turn on. I have ported my laptop's integrated bluetooth to virtualbox, and my output from hciconfig -a is as shown below:

[image: Picture of hciconfig -a]

I really would like bluetooth to work so I can properly test the app, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with VirtualBox and androidx86 under windows 10 with a USB stick Cambridge Silicon Radio and

found this page
http://andex.exton.net/?p=726 
which states

2. Bluetooth doesn’t work. (You can enable Bluetooth and see units though).

I would try with a hd install without Virtual Box.
bye